# New array of indices from larger array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a new array that will have the index numbers of an larger array that will have met a certain condition.

For example, there's a large array of zeros and ones, I would want an array that lists each index that has a one:

```
  int A[] = {1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0};    
  int B[4];    
    ...      
  for(i = 0;i < 4;i++)
  {
     printf("%d \n",B[i]);
  }
```

With the result:

```
0
1
4
5
```

On the small scale (for the above), I have it working by using a nested for loop and the break command:

```
//nested loop 
//reading index
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    int c[10] = {-1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int d[4];

    b = 0;
    for(a = 0;a < 5;)
    {
        for(;b < 10;b++)
        {
            if(c[b] == -1)
            {
                d[a] = b;
                break;
            }

        }
        b++;
        a++;
    }

    for(a = 0;a < 4;)
    {
        printf("%d \n",d[a]);
        a++;
    }
}
```

The issue comes when I try to implement this on the large scale for much larger array set (wherein, I wouldn't know how large the second array needs to be). This is what I have:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 283

int im_index_finder(int inarray[N - 2],int min_or_max);

void main()
{
    double t[N], d[N], velocity[N], averagevelocity[N - 1], n_d[N];
    double dx[N - 1];
    int b[N - 1], d_b[N - 2];
    int i,j,k,a,c,imax_index,imin_index;
    int imax[N - 2], imin[imin_index];

    FILE *fid;

    fid = fopen("squatsedit.csv","r");

    //      Reading the data from csv file, velocity, and average velocity

    for(i = 0;i < N;)
    {
        fscanf(fid, "%lf, %lf", &t[i], &d[i]);
        //printf("%g  %g\n", t[i], d[i]);
        velocity[i] = d[i] / t[i];
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 1;i < N;)
    {
        averagevelocity[i - 1] = (d[i] - d[i-1])/(t[i] - t[i-1]);
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0;i < N;)
    {
        n_d[i] = d[i];
        i++;
    }

    //      Filtering of the distance data

    for(i = 0;i < 2;)
    {
        for(j = 2;j < N;)
        {
            k = j - 1;
            n_d[k] = ( n_d[k - 1] + n_d[k] + n_d[k + 1] )/3;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    //      start of extrema replica

    for(i = 1;i < N;)
    {
        dx[i - 1] = (n_d[i] - n_d[i-1]);
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0;i < N - 1;)
    {                                   //checking peaks for maxima and minima
        if(dx[i] > 0)
        {
            b[i] = 1;                   //b[i] = 1 for positive changes in slope
        }
        else
        {
            b[i] = 0;                   //b[i] = 0 for negative changes in slope
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 1;i < N - 1;)
    {
        d_b[i - 1] = b[i] - b[i - 1]; 
        i++;
    }

    imax_index = im_index_finder(d_b,1);
    imin_index = im_index_finder(d_b,0);

    c = 0;
    for(a = 0;a < imax_index;)
    {
        for(;c < N - 2;c++)
        {
            if(d_b[c] == -1)
            {
                imax[a] = c + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        c++;
        a++;
    }

    c = 0;
    for(a = 0; a < imin_index;)
    {
        for(;c < N - 2;c++)
        {
            if(d_b[c] == 1)
            {
                imin[a] = c + 1;
               break;
            }
        }
        c++;
        a++;
    }

    printf("Our squatsedit is:\n");
    for(i = 0;i < 5;)
    {
        printf("%g   %g \n",t[i],d[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("...\n");
    printf("Our velocities are:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5;)
    {
        printf("%e \n",velocity[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("...\n");
    printf("Our average velocities are:\n");

    for(i = 0;i < 5;)
    {
        printf("%f \n",averagevelocity[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("...\n");
    printf("Our filtered distances are:\n");
    for(i = 0;i < 5;)
    {
        printf("%f \n",n_d[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("...\n");
    printf("Then some differences are:\n");
    for(i = 0;i < 5;)
    {
        printf("%f \n",dx[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("...\n");
    printf("Our positve and negative detector says:\n");
    for(i = 0;i < 5;)
    {
        printf("%d \n",b[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("...\n");
    printf("Our xb equivalent is:\n");
    for(i = 0;i < 10;)
    {
        printf("%d \n",d_b[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("...\n");
    printf("our imax_index is %d \n",imax_index);
    printf("our imin_index is %d \n",imin_index);
    for(i = 0;i < imax_index;)
    {
        printf("%d \n",imax[i]);
        i++;
    }
    //printf("our imin is:\n");
    //for(i = 0;i < imin_index;)
    //{
    //    printf("%d \n",imin[i]);
    //    i++;
    //}

    fclose(fid);

}

int im_index_finder(int inarray[N - 2],int min_or_max)
{
    int a;
    int max_index = 0;
    int min_index = 0;

    for(a = 0;a < N - 2;)
    {
        if(inarray[a] == -1)
        {
            max_index++;
        }
        else if(inarray[a] == 1)
        {
            min_index++;
        }
        a++;
    }

    if(min_or_max = 1)
    {
        return max_index;
    }
    else
    {
        return min_index;
    }
}
```

However, when it displays, what should have been the last seven elements of the imin array are the beginning elements of the imax array.

When I comment out the imin loops, imax presents correctly, but i need the imin as well, can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You are using imin_index in the declaration of imin[], but what value is imin_index?

```
int i,j,k,a,c,imax_index,imin_index;
int imax[N - 2], imin[imin_index];
```

So what is the size of imin[]?

Comment: To elaborate, the declaration of `imin[]` gets its size from the value `imin_index` has *at the point of the declaration* -- `imin[]` will not change size later if `imin_index` changes.

Comment: Indeed - much obliged! Perhaps changing that line to int imax[N - 2], imin[N - 2] would be a sufficient fix.

Comment: The issue with that is the fact that I'm not supposed to know what 'imax_index' or 'imin_index' are. In the terms of what I already know a sample set is, 'imax_index' is 13, with '-1', or dips down in the data sets (the data set represents distance and time, so the dip in distance represents a peak). Like i said, when I comment out the loops for 'imin', it works just fine.

Would it be possible to just initialize the array afterwards? I'll try that.

Comment: You could dynamically allocate memory as you need it using malloc() and realloc(). You can't use an array in your code then declare it later. Are there no limits - the reason you get those errors is most likely because imin_index isn't given a value, it contains some arbitrary value that is being used to specify the size of your array. You are overwriting the memory allocated to imin.

Answer (score 0):

1) loop over main array to find the count of elements that matches your condition. 
2) dynamically allocate an array of size equal to the this count. 
3) loop again your first array and move the matched elements to dynamically allocated second array.